# Mapping objects from Room Persistence

Tags: android-room

I have classes - Subject.java

```
    @Entity(tableName = Constants.SUBJECT_ENTITY)
        public class Subject {

        @PrimaryKey
        private int id;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
        private String name;
        ...
    }
```

Grade.java

```
    @Entity(tableName = Constants.GRADE_ENTITY,
            foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
                    entity = Subject.class,
                    onDelete = CASCADE,
                    parentColumns = "id",
                    childColumns = "subjectId"))
    public class Grade implements Serializable {

        @PrimaryKey
        private int id;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "semester")
        private int semester;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "subjectId")
        private int subjectId;
        ...
    }
```

SubjectAndAllGrades.java

```
    public class SubjectAndAllGrades {

        public int id;
        public String name;

        @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "subjectId")
        public List<Grade> oceny;
        ...
    }
```

I have performed some query in my SubjectDAO

```
    @Query("SELECT distinct s.id as id, s.name as name " +
            "FROM subject s, grade g " +
            "WHERE s.id = g.subjectId " +
            "AND g.semester = :semester ")
    Flowable<List<SubjectAndAllGrades>> getSubjectAndAllItsGradesForSemester(int semester);
```

In this query as you can probably guess Im trying to select all Subjects with its grades with specific semester. However results of this query return list of SubjectAndAllGrades objects connected by subjectId key, but with no respect to the condition
    g.semester = :semester 
How could I achive this query?